# SwiftUI: How to change default background color

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm wondering how to change the default system background color given to iOS apps. For example, when you create a blank XCode project, the canvas is, by default, white. Is there a way to change this default color, without creating a separate background view?

Comment: Change color schema to dark and it will become black. That's it. For now there are not more variants for system(!) background colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify it directly `systemBackground` because it is declared as a read-only class property. But it is declared as `open` though, so you can do something like:

```
class MyColor: UIColor {

    override class var systemBackground: UIColor {
        return .systemRed
    }

}
```

And use it like `MyColor.systemBackground`.

I find this approach unnecessary though, I would just recommend creating your own utility/helper class to define your own color palette and avoid inheriting from UIColor.